# Why I can't access json properties with dot (.) operator while passing a var through $.getjson()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a $getJSON() that i want to pass a var through how ever i always get **undefined** in console log.

I have done this before i just cant seem to figure out why this isnt working.

Any help would be appreciated.

here is my example

```js
{
    "harry": {
        "example": "test",
        "example1": "test",
    }
    "james": {
        "example": "test",
        "example1": "test",
    }
    "ben": {
        "example": "test",
        "example1": "test",
    }
}
```

```js
  var usersidno = $("#hiddenid").html();
  $.getJSON(
  "http://localhost/example/file.json",
  function(json) {
  console.log(json.usersidno);
  });
```

```html
<div id="hiddenid">harry</div>
```

Comment: in which variable you get `undefined`?

Comment: can you try logging 'json' object that you are receiving inside the function and see if there exists a property inside json with name useridno? as it seems there's no property named useridno inside the object.

Comment: Shouldn't Harry, James, and Ben have comas between them?

Comment: if i console.log(json) i get all the name, as normal.

Comment: Looks like what you're trying to do here is `json[usersidno]`, not `json.usersidno`. You want to get the property whose name matches the value in `usersidno`, not the property named `usersidno`.

Comment: @BearNithi usersidno is undefined.
but im guessing

its searching the json for usersidno not what its var is for.
which should be harry.

If that makes sence

Because

console.log(json.harry);
Returns correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to access an object's (JSON) property dynamically (using a variable or expression), you should use **square bracket** notation.

`[your expression or variable inside square brackets]`. i.e, `json[useridno]`

```
 var usersidno = $("#hiddenid").html();
 $.getJSON(
   "http://localhost/example/file.json",
   function(json) {
      console.log(json[usersidno]); // try to use square brackets
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of ,your issue I have used an api ,that gives back a json ,You can use [] annotatiton to access object properties.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var user = $("#hiddenid").html()
console.log(typeof user)

 $.getJSON(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
  function(json) {
  let js=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))
 console.log(js[user]);
  console.log(js.user);//undefined
  console.log(js)
 
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hiddenid">userId</div>
```

Explanation:

```
var userid = 'userId';
console.log(x.userid); // it looks for x.userid, which throws undefined,if it does'nt exists
console.log(x[userid]); // looks for x['userId'] which it will find
```

Have a look at [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)